# Print Json Based On ID Value PHP

Tags: php, json

I am getting json data from two API link.

First For-Loop Consists of Market ID(Which Consists of All ID But Second Loop doesnt have all ID)   and BaseCurrencyCode

```
First Loop Output :
MarketID -> BaseCurrency Code
18 -> LTC/BTC 
19 -> UNO/BTC 
20 -> SYS/BTC 
21 -> DOGE/BTC 
22 -> KOBO/BTC 
23 -> BITZ/BTC 
24 -> DGC/BTC 
25 -> MEC/BTC
```

Second Loop Output :

```
MarketID -> CurrencyValue
18 -> 0.01588636 
19 -> 0.01120000 
21 -> 0.00000065 
22 -> 0.00000711 
24 -> 0.00000877 
25 -> 0.00000761 
26 -> 0.00000007 
31 -> 0.00002200 
34 -> 0.00000445
```

*i Need to Combine Two For Loops
And Output Looking For*

```
MarketID  BaseCurrency   Value 
18   ->   LTC/BTC      0.01588636
```

**Important :- If BTC is Basecurrency , Then Print All BaseCurrency BTC Pairs 
Similarly LTC base pair  ETH Pair DOGE pair**

Below PHP Script

```
<?php
include 'pappu.php';
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");




$grabs=ngegrab('https://www.coinexchange.io/api/v1/getmarkets');
$jsons = json_decode($grabs);

if($jsons)
foreach ($jsons->result as $sam)
{
  $market= $sam->MarketID;
  $marketcode=$sam->MarketAssetCode;
  $basecurrency=$sam->BaseCurrencyCode;

echo " $market -> $marketcode/$basecurrency <br/>";

}

$grabs=ngegrab('https://www.coinexchange.io/api/v1/getmarketsummaries');
$jsons = json_decode($grabs);

if($jsons)
foreach ($jsons->result as $sam)
{
  $market= $sam->MarketID;
  $price= $sam->LastPrice;
echo " $market -> $price <br/>";

}
```

Comment: I would do this as two passes 1) create an array with the values from the two arrays stored in one array keyed on 'market_id'.   2) I would then print that array in a separate pass.

Comment: @RyanVincent could you please show some example code